# Ezproxy Access Through SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

When I am working at the University, the program I use for managing papers (`Papers2`, from **mekentosj**), connects to the `EZproxy`, so that it can download papers.

When I am at home, I **can't** do this. My question is can I somehow setup an **SSH** tunnel to the University so that the program `Papers` can log into the `EZproxy` from home?.

**P.S.** As a follow-up to comments, I have the right to set up an **SSH** tunnel at our University, on my **Linux** machine.

Comment: Bounty or not - the question is too broad and unclear. Please update it and describe the situation in more detail. E.g. how should anyone know if there is an active SSH server at your university on the target host or if you have the right to set up one?

Comment: I have clarified it, I think

Comment: Hm, well - a clear question is something different to me. Anyway, I tried to answer based on what you wrote. Any feedback to my answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you stated that you have **SSH** access to your university, you can use [**Dynamic Port Forwarding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding#Dynamic_port_forwarding):

- `ssh -D LOCAL_PORT USER@UNIVERSITY_MACHINE_IP` allows you to forward each connection through the **`LOCAL_PORT`** you specified on your machine.

  1. Go your `OS`'s connection settings
  2. Check `Manual Proxy Settings`
  3. Enter `127.0.0.1` in the `SOCKS` field.
  4. Enter `LOCAL_PORT` you choose to `Port` field.

Now, every connection protocol (*HTTP*, *FTP*, etc.) will be *forwarded through the university machine you **connected***.

**Note:**

- Be sure to select an unused port on your computer bigger than 1024 as `LOCAL_PORT`
- You can only do this while your **SSH** connection is still alive.
- You can also configure browser-only forwarding from the settings of your browser of choice.

Answer (score 2):

Still not enough information to create a pre-fabricated solution for you. Anyway, a few resources:

- [How to set Papers library proxy](http://support.mekentosj.com/kb/how-to/configure-papers-to-work-with-your-library-proxy): I do not know if you can create your own proxy, e.g. on localhost:2048, tunnelling through to the university.
- [How many (and which) proxy ports does EZproxy use?](http://www.oclc.org/support/services/ezproxy/documentation/howmanyports.en.html) This should help you determine the SSH tunnel settings you need for your connection
- Your university's EZproxy administrator: Ask her if she can tell you how to set up remote access. Maybe there is an official way to set this up, possibly an already existing, externally accessible proxy URL or SSH hopping station, maybe a VPN or whatever.